# Connection String Error (Given path not supported)

Tags: c#, database-connection

I have seen a lot of the same error but in different situations. My particular error is thrown right at the first SqlConnection line. I have no compilation errors so why is it failing?

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].
    ConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertRecord", sqlConn);

sqlConn.Open();

command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", txtDate.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title", TitleTextBox.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", FirstName.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", LastName.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comments", Comments.Text));

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

`WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString` is the following string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebActivityLog-20140806121543;Integrated Security=SSPI;
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|C:\Users\v667719\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebActivityLog\WebActivityLog\App_Data\Records.mdf
```

(Just without the newlines. Those were added for formatting.)

Comment: Well, we aren't psychic. Show us `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString` and then we'll continue from there.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know I should have included that. `<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebActivityLog-20140806121543;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|C:\Users\v667719\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebActivityLog\WebActivityLog\App_Data\Records.mdf"/>`

Comment: Do you have database created with name `aspnet-WebActivityLog-20140806121543` in your local sql server?

Comment: When I first created the database I had a failure, so I deleted the db, and created the Records one.

Comment: What's the database name that you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Records.mdf in the App_Data folder.

Comment: Did you finally end up setting the path for .mdf like `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Records.mdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting compile time error because the connection string is defined in the configuration and at compile time it is not going to check for its validity.
You have `|DataDirectory|` defined in the AttachDBFilename along with the full path. Build the connection string again.

You can use the Server Explorer window in Visual Studio (open with the menu View/Server Explorer) and connect to your server/database from that window and you can get the connection string from there.

For correct format of connection string refer [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com).